# Run html2text using parallel

Tags: python, html, linux, terminal, parallel-processing

I am using `html2text` from [Github](https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text) in-which I was able to run-it on all the `.html` files in my folder using `for file in *.html; do html2text "$file" > "$file.txt"; done` but it's some-what slow. How can I use html2text with parallel on all my `.html` files?

Comment: Do you have access to parallel hardware, in the first place?

Comment: what hardware ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original answer was:

```
for file in *.html
do
    html2text "$file" > "$file.txt" & 
done
```

The & sign at end of command tells bash to put the command in background and return control to calling place.

Not sure if it will work well for 1000s of files as it would spawn a new process for each file.

---

However, as OP asked for this to work for millions of files, this is obviously not feasible, as it would spawn millions of background processes, potentially hanging the machine.

### What you have to understand is that processing millions of files *WILL* take more time, exactly depending on your hardware and OS limits. Technically a million more times than single file.

The reason the above answer seemed to work for you for 100 of files instantly, was because you got command prompt back immediately. However, it does **not** mean that the work was finished at that point, because all those background processes might be still working until they finish, even though you can do something else meanwhile.

You could theoretically divide the file list in chunks and work chunk by chunk, however, after testing this approach I do not think you will get the end result much faster than doing parallel.

**So, based on the number of files you have to process, I *would* suggest running parallel as you yourself found out, maybe with tweaking the number of parallel jobs significantly though.**

So something like this should work:

```
find . -type f -name \*html > FLIST
parallel --a FLIST -j 1000 'html2text {} > {.}.txt'
```

Note, this is syntax for OP's Python version of html2text. For options using eg. Ubuntu distro available html2text binary package, please see previous edit of the answer.

This will do your html in chunks of 1000 parallel files and not use piping (which can sometimes slow down things considerably).

If this is too slow, try increasing -j to maybe 10000 -- but then you are venturing into hardware/operating system limitations of having 10000 parallel processes spawned all the time.

Comment: @mrM no it isn't, it has an & sign in the right place, if you bother to read the answer

Comment: My mistake, your code have made html2text output almost instantly. Thanks man!

Comment: Gnudiff your code works instantly on 100th of files, but when I test on millions of files it slows down somehow. Is there a way to set chunks of files, or perhaps divide my 1,000,000 files into 100 files per folder and then run this code on each folder?

Comment: I thought about it, yes, there is a way, I will post it a little later when I am at computer

Comment: When running your second code line, I get `parallel: Error: A semaphore does not take input from neither stdin nor a file`

Comment: @mrM try to run without --bg or with --fg if it didn't help

Comment: When running without `--bg` I get `html2text: error: no such option: -o`

Comment: When running with `--fg` I get `parallel: Error: A semaphore does not take input from neither stdin nor a file`

Comment: Apparently you are using some python version of html2text. Not sure how fast it is. I will edit the answer to reflect this, but if you are looking for speed, you might be better off installing distribution specific compiled binary html2text package, if it is available for you. For example, on Ubuntu I did "sudo apt install html2text" to use the command.

Answer (score 0):

For others in a similar situation, using `parallel` reduces time by more than HALF.

Comment: Well have you tried the updated version of my answer and have you tried tweaking the -j parameter?

Comment: I have tried the version from the Ubuntu repository & it was very bad and buggy even after tweaking. The html2text version from Github was better with parallel reducing the time by ~2-3 times.

Comment: Gnudiff is it possible to delete each `.html` file after it was converted? when runing `parallel --a FLIST -j 4 'html2text {} > {.}.txt'
`

Comment: it is in principle another question, but yes should be possible, I will add details. If my answer worked for you, BTW, please accept it.

Comment: this should work for removing files after processing but it will only work if html2text exited successfully (no error when processing file): parallel --a FLIST -j 1000 'html2text {} > {.}.text && rm {}'